# require() and exports are not recognized in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I saw a lot of answers about this problem but still I cannot fix this.

I have three modules:

```
controller.ts
modules.ts
view.ts
```

and a HTML file:

```
view.html
```

As you expect, I have to import some functions from controller module
but browser-side cannot run import/export/require functions.

I tried a lot, also I could not install webpack and use it. It says "you need webpack cli".

I am open to any recommendation

Comment: It's already a recommandation. Check documentation about Webpack or Rollup for instance

Comment: Now, I have a problem about webpack bundle javascript file. I created an index.js file in a seperate project, I bundle it with webpack and I can get rid of exports and require errors but not I cannot see my function defined in index.js in order to use as onclick action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this:

- If you only need to support very modern browsers you could use the
  [ES6 import statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) (Requires Chrome 61, Safari 10.1, Firefox
  60).
- Since you are using TypeScript you could structure your code in [namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) (previously called internal modules) and generate with the --outfile parameter which combines all your modules into one output file.
- As already suggested you could use a bundler like Webpack or Rollup which would also combine your modules into a single output file.

Comment: how should i use namespaces?